# JPA @ManyToOne automatically remove parent when last child is removed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an unidirectional mapping from child to parent by @ManyToOne like this:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private ParentEntity parent;
```

I it possible to remove parent, when last child is removed without having reference from ParentEntity to ChildEntities? None of the annotations I tried seems to be working.

Comment: @Naman this doesnt work because you get a "foreign key" exception when it was not the last child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no method from jpa to do this. 
But you can check the number of child entitys in your service in the deletion method and than delete parent if it was the last.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not do it only with annotation: hibernate does not know about first, second or last child. To solve task you can write `@PostRemove` interceptor (in jpa, or listener in hibernate), in which calculate case "last child", call entity manager and remove parent. Do DAO operation in entity is not perfect, but if you really want....